# Sort relation laravel

Tags: laravel, relation

In single of restaurant. I foreach typeoffoods relation.

```
 Route::bind('slug', function ($slug) {
    return \Modules\Restaurant\Entities\Restaurant::where('slug',$slug)
        ->with('typeoffood.foods','categories','city','slides')
        ->firstOrFail();
});
```

But now I want sort typeoffood relation by column (Example: column is created_at)
How to do this, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have Restaurant model then add orderBy on typeoffood() relatitionship method ex:

Restaurant.php

```
public function typeoffood()
{
    return $this->hasMany('something')->orderBy('created_at');
}
```